# Testing reduce functions when rereduce is true

Tags: couchdb

I have just written a nontrivial reduce function in which the `rereduce` execution path differs from the standard `reduce`.

It is my understanding that `rereduce` is only performed in certain situations; specifically, to merge `reduce` operations performed across multiple nodes or large ranges of keys.

As my local development environment runs on a single node with a relatively small dataset, how can I effectively test the behaviour of my reduce function in a rereduce scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a script to generate larger amounts of realistic dummy data. The only way I've been able to test my map-reduce's are with real or fake data, but lots of it.

It's a side benefit and perversely fun, but you also get a good idea of how long it will take for indexing, and view requests, and get a peek at how your app will do at scale. Load testing never hurts.

Comment: Went with this in the end. It seems it only takes 100 or so documents before this kicks in (at least, it did in my case - I don't know what the criteria are) and, as you say, it's useful to test with realistic numbers of documents anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I don't test my scripts in couchdb. I use instead:

- a JS-IDE ([Webstorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/))
- behaviour driven testing ([jasmine](https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html))
- a full suite of JSON test documents
- a self written runner script that mocks the call for map and reduce functions.
- an external version control system to manage changes to the queries.

This way I can regression and unit test my map and reduce functions whilst at the same time support a level of complexity that can just not be supported in couchdb.

Comment: Thanks - maybe I should have specified in the question, but I am not looking particularly for a unit testing based solution. The reason for this is that it would assume the correctness of my test harness and mocks' responses. What I really need is a proper end-to-end integration test with CouchDB itself. In the absence of a way to force the parameter I will probably just go with uploading a large amount of data.